# Creating a Search Record Function Python SQLite3

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I am currently working on a coursework project for school and it is a database system with a user interface using Tkinter, Python and SQLite3. I have made a form to add, delete, update and search for customers. I am able to display the result from a single field, however, I am struggling to get the message box to display all the fields, which is what I would like it to do. I have attached photos of the form along with the code. Thank you in advance.

```
    def SearchCustomer(self):
        customerid = self.CustomerEntry.get();
        with sqlite3.connect("LeeOpt.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            search_customer = ('''SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = ?''')
            cursor.execute(search_customer, [(customerid)])
            results = cursor.fetchall()

            if results:
                for i in results:
                    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification",i[0])
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you showed only the first column (`i[0]`) from result.

Since there should be only one record for a specific customer ID, you should use `fetchone()` instead of `fetchall()`, then you can show the whole record as below:

```
    def SearchCustomer(self):
        customerid = self.CustomerEntry.get()
        with sqlite3.connect("LeeOpt.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            search_customer = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = ?"
            cursor.execute(search_customer, [customerid])
            result = cursor.fetchone() # there should be only one record for specific customer ID
            if result:
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", "\n".join(str(x) for x in result))
```